# Conditional Unpivot SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table which looks like this `<SubCodeReport3>` which has a column called `Rank`. For each row I need to the what is the Rank and based on that value I need to unpivot SubCode columns (SubCode1,SubCode2 & Subcode3 etc) and convert them into rows.

[image]

As seen above for a 
Rank 2 Subcode1 & SubCode2 have been unpivoted
Rank 1 SubCode1 has been unpivoted 
Rank 3 Subcode1, Subcode2 & SubCode3 have been unpivoted.

there will not be case where the Rank is higher than the no. of available SubCode columns. Any Ideas?

Cursor though rows ?

Here is some SQL to create this sample table

```
    USE TESTDB
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SubCodeReport3]    Script Date: 10/6/2015 2:27:49 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SubCodeReport3](
    [ S-ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Rank] [smallint] NULL,
    [AGE] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SchoolCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubCode1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubCode2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubCode3] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubCode4] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SubCode5] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
INSERT [dbo].[SubCodeReport3] ([ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]) VALUES (N'25', 1, N'23', N'KEN-009', N'ENG', N'MAT', N'ZOO', N'', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[SubCodeReport3] ([ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]) VALUES (N'26', 1, N'21', N'DLK-009', N'ENG', N'', N'', N'', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[SubCodeReport3] ([ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]) VALUES (N'27', 2, N'25', N'DLK-006', N'MAT', N'ENG', N'STAT', N'', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[SubCodeReport3] ([ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]) VALUES (N'28', 1, N'21', N'HLI-005', N'ENG', N'', N'', N'', N'')
INSERT [dbo].[SubCodeReport3] ([ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]) VALUES (N'30', 3, N'22', N'INN-009', N'ENG', N'MAT', N'ZOO', N'GEO', N'')
```

Comment: Sample data for rank column does not correspond to question, you said rank would not be greater than number of columns but there are values 867 and greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with a CTE or derived table that does a full unpivot of the table, and adds a partitioned row_number so that for each row in the original table, SubCode1 will be on row_number 1, SubCode2 on row_number 2, etc.

Then select from that CTE where row_number is less than or equal to [Rank].

Answer (score 0):

You need to CROSS JOIN to a table with sequential numbers:

```
with cte as
 (
  select 1 as n 
  union all select 2 
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
 )
select Rank, Age, SchoolCode, 
   case n
      when 1 then SubCode1 
      when 2 then SubCode2 
      when 3 then SubCode3 
      when 4 then SubCode4 
      when 5 then SubCode5 
   end as SubCode
from SubCodeReport3
join cte 
  on n <= rank
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72c32/1)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the number of subcodes you can always do this and your question asks how to UNPIVOT:

```
select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode]
  from (select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1]
          from SubCodeReport3 SCR3
         where SCR3.[Rank] = 1) R1
         unpivot (SubCode FOR Subject IN (SubCode1)) as unpvt1
UNION ALL         
select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode]
  from (select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2]
          from SubCodeReport3 SCR3
         where SCR3.[Rank] = 2) R1
         unpivot (SubCode FOR Subject IN (SubCode1, SubCode2)) as unpvt2         
UNION ALL         
select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode]
  from (select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3]
          from SubCodeReport3 SCR3
         where SCR3.[Rank] = 3) R1
         unpivot (SubCode FOR Subject IN (SubCode1, SubCode2, SubCode3)) as unpvt3
UNION ALL         
select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode]
  from (select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4]
          from SubCodeReport3 SCR3
         where SCR3.[Rank] = 4) R1
         unpivot (SubCode FOR Subject IN (SubCode1, SubCode2, SubCode3, SubCode4)) as unpvt4
UNION ALL         
select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode]
  from (select [ S-ID], [Rank], [AGE], [SchoolCode], [SubCode1], [SubCode2], [SubCode3], [SubCode4], [SubCode5]
          from SubCodeReport3 SCR3
         where SCR3.[Rank] = 5) R1
         unpivot (SubCode FOR Subject IN (SubCode1, SubCode2, SubCode3, SubCode4, SubCode5)) as unpvt5
```

[See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6985a7/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
WITH CodesReportCTE 
(
       [Number]
      ,[ S-ID]
      ,[Rank]
      ,[AGE]
      ,[SchoolCode]
      ,[Code]
)
AS
(

SELECT 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY [ S-ID],[SchoolCode] ORDER BY [ S-ID],[SchoolCode]) AS Number
      ,[ S-ID]
      ,[Rank]
      ,[AGE]
      ,[SchoolCode]
      ,up.Code [Code]
  FROM [dbo].[SubCodeReport3]
  UNPIVOT
  (
  Code
  for x in (SubCode1,SubCode2,SubCode3,SubCode4,SubCode5) ) up
  WHERE up.Code <> ' '

)

SELECT 
       --[Number]
      --,
      [ S-ID]
      ,[Rank]
      ,[AGE]
      ,[SchoolCode]
      ,[Code]

      FROM CodesReportCTE
      WHERE Number <= [Rank]
```